# Is there a way to get same results while running mmlspark lightgbm twice?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, azure-databricks, lightgbm

I am using mmlspark version 0.17 on azure databricks. I have a regression problem and am using the LightGbmRegressor.

The issue is that everytime I run the model with the same parameters and on the same data, I get different results.

Is there any way to fix this ?

Details of the process:

- The training and test data are parquet files and I read them each time to train and test respectively.
- The baggingseed is also set at 10 everytime.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: lightGbmRegressor has a `random_state` parameter, this seed is provided to the C++ engine to pick the same random output given the same seed, read the doc here [link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html), also

Comment: @EladCohen Thank you but i am talking about the mmlspark versionof light gbm (pyspark) which does not have a random_state parameter. 
The one you are referring is of the scikit-learn API (python) which has a random_state parameter.

Comment: I face the same issue. you can see update on this issue here https://github.com/microsoft/SynapseML/issues/564.